# Creating an array with random numbers on button Click (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, random

Ah.. I'm a beginner. I cant come up with a method that would generate an array of random numbers on button click. Another click should make a new array an so on.

like.. 
first click
TheNumbers = new int [3] {1, 2, 3};

second click
TheNumbers2 = new int [3] {4, 5, 7};

etc..

Comment: Check articles on the net, for example: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generating-random-number-and-string-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Break it down into smaller tasks. For example you could search for something like 'generate random number c#' then for 'initialize array c#' and then 'c# button click'. When search for anything related to UI you should also include what UI framework you're using, not just c#. This could be WPF, asp.net (razor/blazor), windows forms,..

Comment: Yeah.. was badly phrased, sorry. Using Unity. I can generate randoms with Random.Range (x, x); Know how the UI button works and can make simple arrays.. 

Problem is making it dynamic, that you can add one or multiple arrays with simple button.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you. I assume you're working with `WinForms`

Read [Random Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8)

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8
        // The default seed value is derived from the system clock, which has finite resolution. 
        // As a result, on the .NET Framework only, different Random objects that are created in 
        // close succession by a call to the parameterless constructor will have identical default 
        // seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers. This problem 
        // can be avoided by using a single Random object to generate all random numbers.
        private readonly Random objRandom = new Random();

        //Everytime the button is clicked, this array is loaded with 3 random numbers
        private int[] theNumbers;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            theNumbers = GenerateThreeRandomsEachLessThanTen();

            //just to demo the creation of the numbers
            textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, theNumbers);
        }

        private int[] GenerateThreeRandomsEachLessThanTen()
        {
            return new int[] { objRandom.Next(10), objRandom.Next(10), objRandom.Next(10) };
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(86, 24);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Go";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 63);
            this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(203, 91);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(234, 179);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Randoms";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    }
}
```

**Output from clicking on "Go" button 3 times**

[image]